# Redmine agile plugin installation failure - No such file to load -- agile_data

Tags: redmine, agile, redmine-plugins

I have Redmine 2 on Ubuntu and want to install additional agile plugin. I have added redmine_agile folder downloaded from http://www.redminecrm.com/projects/agile/pages/1 to /usr/share/redmine/lib/plugins and used commands:

```
sudo bundle install --without development test

sudo bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=redmine_agile RAILS_ENV=production
```

After last one, I get:

```
(in /usr/share/redmine)
rake aborted!
No such file to load -- agile_data

Tasks: TOP => redmine:plugins:migrate => environment
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've unpacked plugin into incorrect folder. It should be unpacked into /usr/share/redmine/plugins. Migration command should be run from /usr/share/redmine/